# Docker NVIDIA GPU Passthrough intermittently fails after random periods

Tags: docker, nvidia-docker

I'm currently utilizing GPU passthrough in a Docker container by running the following commands:

```
sudo docker run -d \
  --name=jellyfin \
  --runtime=nvidia \
  --gpus all \
  -e NVIDIA_DRIVER_CAPABILITIES=all \
  -e NVIDIA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=all \
  jellyfin/jellyfin:latest
```

Initially, the setup works fine, as shown in this screenshot, with the Docker container able to access the GPU without issues.

[image: GPU Passthrough Working]

However, after a random amount of time (ranging from a day to a week), the GPU passthrough randomly fails, resulting in the container being unable to utilize the GPU, as depicted in this screenshot. (Restarting the docker container will then fix it again)

[image: GPU Passthrough not working]

If anyone has any ideas or can help me out with this id appreciate it.

Environment Details:
OS - Linux Manjaro
Docker Version - 25.0.4, build 1a576c5

I also looked in the docker logs, and other than giving errors that it cant access the gpu, there was nothing of note

```
[AVHWDeviceContext @ 0x55b4273e0440] cu->cuInit(0) failed -> CUDA_ERROR_NO_DEVICE: no CUDA-capable device is detected
Device creation failed: -542398533.
Failed to set value 'cuda=cu:0' for option 'init_hw_device': Generic error in an external library
Error parsing global options: Generic error in an external library
```

Comment: Randomness suggests that this might be a memory issue. How much RAM available on the host?

Comment: 64gb, so i doubt thats the issue

Comment: Nope, you're right!